# CrystalReportViewer in ASP.net shows black

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, crystal-reports

I just switched from WinForms to WebForms. I'm trying to display a report previously created for WinForm application in ASP.NET. All I get is empty page (I'm testing on IIS).

Here is a code:

```
protected void GenerateReport()
{
    SalesOrder r1 = new SalesOrder();
    var path = Server.MapPath("App_Code/SalesOrder.rpt");
    r1.Load(path);
    r1.SetParameterValue("SONumber", 266305);
    r1.SetParameterValue("BackOrder", false);
    r1.SetParameterValue("SuppressCost", false);
    r1.SetParameterValue("SuppressPrice", false);
    r1.SetParameterValue("SuppressTotal", false);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = r1;
}
```

I admit that the problem could be with Integrated Security of my SQL server. This report usually launches on domain client computers by domain users with access permissions to SQL. Since I'm new to it can someone help me troubleshoot the problem if not find the major problem with the code above?

Comment: Correction - shows blank not black

Answer (score 0):

I was able to capture report's query to SQL server in SQL Server profiler. It came in as a correct user and was successfully executed so the problem is in the presentation. This question, in this form is now mute.